# Retry tests that failed in @BeforeMethod using testng

Tags: java, testng

I'm using the following code to retry failed tests:

```
 private int retryCount = 1;
private static final int maxRetryCount = 2;

@Override
public boolean retry(ITestResult iTestResult) {
    if(retryCount <= maxRetryCount) {
        System.out.println("retry test "+iTestResult.getName());
        retryCount++;
        System.out.println(iTestResult.getThrowable());
        return true;
   }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Transformer:

```
public class AnnotationTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {
@Override
public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
    annotation.setRetryAnalyzer(MyRetryAnalyzer.class);
}
```

testng.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="suit1" configfailurepolicy="continue">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="AnnotationTransformer"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="all-tests">
        <classes>
            <class name="ClassTests"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The problem is that if the test failed in @BeforeMethod the test is skipped and does not run again.
any ideas?

Comment: Where and how `retryCount` and `maxRetryCount` defined?

Comment: please see the update

Comment: What test is run in @BeforeMethod? Is there some dependency between tests?

Comment: Retry Analyzer only works for `@Test` methods. For configuration methods, you need to try via call Backs. Please refer following threads: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/pull/2262 https://rationaleemotions.com/retry_configuration_methods/